# what does num_days=int((end_dt-start_dt)/np.timetable64(1,'D')) mean? why does the function np.timetable has a 64 at the end of it?

Tags: numpy

what does the command code num_days=int((end_dt-start_dt)/np.timetable64(1,'D')) mean?
why does the function np.timetable has a 64 at the end of it?

Comment: Are you sure you have mentioned the right method? I can't find any `np.timetable` method in the numpy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The function that is employed here is not `np.timetable64()` but rather `np.timedelta64()`. What the code you posted does is the following: It first calculates the length of the timespan between two dates (end_dt and start_dt) through `end_dt - start_dt` and then divides this timespan by the length of one day. The length of one day in numpy is obtained by creating a so called "timedelta", in this example using `np.timedelta64(1, 'D')` where 'D' indicates the unit of the timedelta (D stands for day) and `1` is the length of this timedelta given in that unit.

The result of the calculation is therefore the length of the timespan between start_dt and end_dt in days. You can find further information on Timedeltas [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic).

The link to the documentation provided above also explains that

> The data type is called “datetime64”, so named because “datetime” is already taken by the datetime library included in Python.